# Stuck in UploadFromStream when disconnected from internet

Tags: c#, winforms, azure, try-catch

I have a try/catch method, as shown below.  When the internet connection is down, the code blocks in the try, and does not enter the catch, and the application stops responding. When the internet connection is back, the problem is gone, and everything works fine.

This a part of my code:

```
using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(strLocatie))
{
    try
    {
        blobSAS.UploadFromStream(fileStream);
    }
    catch
    {
    }
}
```

Can I set a timeout such that when the try block takes longer than 1000ms the code automatically goes to the catch?

Whole method:

```
public void uploadImages(string strLocatie, string naamBestand, string directoryname)
{
    try
    {
        string dag = DateTime.Now.Day.ToString();
        if (dag.Length == 1)
        {
            string temp = dag;
            dag = "0" + temp;
        }
        string maand = DateTime.Now.Month.ToString();
        if (maand.Length == 1)
        {
            string temp = maand;
            maand = "0" + temp;
        }
        if (signature == null)
        {
            getKey();
        }
        string datum = dag + "-" + maand + "-" + DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = new CloudBlobClient(sUrl, new StorageCredentialsSharedAccessSignature(signature));
        CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference(container1);
        blobContainer.GetDirectoryReference(sUrl + container1);
        CloudBlockBlob blobSAS = new CloudBlockBlob(sUrl + container1 + "/" + directoryname + "/" + datum + "/" + naamBestand,
                        new StorageCredentialsSharedAccessSignature(signature));
        using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(strLocatie))
        {
            try
            {
                blobSAS.UploadFromStream(fileStream);
            }
            catch
            {
            }
        }
        File.Delete(strLocatie);
    }
    catch
    {
    }

}
```

And if the internet connection is allready down, before starting the application, the catch works perfect...

Comment: what is blobSAS its type?

Comment: blobSAS is a CloubBlockBlob

Comment: You could test the internet connection before trying to upload and then skip that portion of code if there is no connection. Something like (and this is pseudo-code) 

if(!InternetConnected)
{
   Upload code
}
else
{
    Catch code
}

Comment: @Kobunite what if the Internet connection goes down when in that call?

Comment: then the application stops responding

Comment: @Default - You'd need to keep some form of try/catch to handle errors if the connection drops in the middle of the upload. Personally I'd prefer to be able to differentiate between the internet not being available before upload and it dropping in the middle of an upload.

Comment: @Kobunite what if the Internet drops between the `if (InternetConnected)` and `Upload code`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the blobrequestoptions of your CloudBlockBlob. Here you can set a timeout. However it would be better to upload the file in a backgroundworker. This way your application is always responsive.

[blobrequestoptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.blobrequestoptions.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You may set a timeout on the blobClient

```
 var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=<YOURACCOUNTNAME>;AccountKey=<YOURACCOUNTKEY>");
_blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
_blobClient.Timeout = new System.TimeSpan(1,0,0);
```

Then you could also set parallel settings that appears to spread the copy across multiple threads. If you have big bandwidth you can increase the thread number below because Azure accepts blobs broken into blocks in any order of arrival.

```
_blobClient.ParallelOperationThreadCount = 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a [Timeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storageclient.cloudblobclient.timeout.aspx) for request on the `CloudBlobClient` that is associated with the `CloudBlockBlob`. The default value is 90 seconds.

The CloudBlockBlob provides the property `ServiceClient` to access the instance of CloudBlobClient

But i´m not sure if this solves your problem.

You can also try to use a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storageclient.cloudblob.enduploadfromstream.aspx) to upload your stream to the cloud, so that your application keeps responsible and uploads the data in the background.

Also does the class CloudBlockBlob provide methods [BeginUploadFromStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storageclient.cloudblockblob_methods.aspx) and [EndUploadFromStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storageclient.cloudblob.enduploadfromstream.aspx) to upload data asynchron.

Answer (score 1):

There's a [timeout property in the `BlobRequestOption`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/sv-se/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storageclient.blobrequestoptions.timeout%28en-us%29.aspx)s from the overloaded call to `UploadFromStream`.

Would it work specifying the timeout, something like:

```
BlobRequestOptions blobRequestOptions = new BlobRequestOptions();
blobRequestOptions.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20.0)
blobSAS.UploadFromStream(fileStream, blobRequestOptions);
```